# In hibernate using CriteriaBuilder how to add condition to left join immediately and not as part of where condition?

Tags: hibernate, join, jpa-2.0, criteria-api

I want criteriabuilder to put AND condition immediately with join (1st left join in below query).
But When I put condition in predicate it adds if to final where clause.

I want output like this:

```
    select
            *
        from
            milestone milestone0_ 
        left outer join
            disc_user_milestone_watch userswatch1_ 
                on milestone0_.id=userswatch1_.milestone_id AND userswatch1_.disc_user_id=2  
        left outer join
            disc_user discuser2_ 
                on userswatch1_.disc_user_id=discuser2_.id cross 
        join
            campaign campaign3_ cross 
        join
            department department4_ 
        where
            milestone0_.campaign=campaign3_.id 
            and milestone0_.department=department4_.id;
```

But after putting condition in predicate I get that AND condition in final where clause.
Currently I am getting like this:

```
    select
            *
        from
            milestone milestone0_ 
        left outer join
            disc_user_milestone_watch userswatch1_ 
                on milestone0_.id=userswatch1_.milestone_id   
        left outer join
            disc_user discuser2_ 
                on userswatch1_.disc_user_id=discuser2_.id cross 
        join
            campaign campaign3_ cross 
        join
            department department4_ 
        where
            milestone0_.campaign=campaign3_.id 
            and milestone0_.department=department4_.id 
            AND userswatch1_.disc_user_id=2;
```

What is a way to add AND condition immediately to join ?

My current code looks like this:

```
    EntityManager em = Milestone.entityManager();
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(UserMilestoneWatchStatus.class);

    Root milestoneRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Milestone.class);
    Join milestonediscUserJoin = milestoneRoot.join("usersWatching", JoinType.LEFT);

    // this is used for extending the milestone table to the user table
    Expression userId = milestonediscUserJoin.get("id"); // id
    int currUserId = Integer.parseInt(params.get("currUserId").toString());

    milestoneRoot.alias("x");
    criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.construct(UserMilestoneWatchStatus.class, milestoneRoot, userId));
    criteriaQuery.distinct(true);

    List predicatesList = new ArrayList();
    predicatesList.add(criteriaBuilder.or(criteriaBuilder.equal(userId, currUserId), criteriaBuilder.isNull(userId)));

    criteriaQuery.where(criteriaBuilder.and(predicatesList.toArray(new Predicate[predicatesList.size()]))).orderBy(sort);
```

Whats is way to add AND condition immediately to join and not in where ?

Comment: As an aside: *without* Criteria, but in plain JPQL, one could use the Hibernate-specific `WITH` to add *additional* clauses to the join, like `left join disc_user d with  w.disc_user_id = d.id`.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to do that. JPA 2.0 does not support join with ON clause. Possibly it will be part of [JPA 2.1](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=338).